# FileLogTraceListener remove oldest logs when there is no space

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, trace

Is there a way to instruct FileLogTraceListener to delete old log files when it has no enough space on disk?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the [`ReserveDiskSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.filelogtracelistener.reservediskspace.aspx) Property to your preferred size and the [`DiskSpaceExhaustedBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.filelogtracelistener.diskspaceexhaustedbehavior.aspx)  Property to `ThrowException`.

Then add Try...Catch blocks around all code that writes to the log and delete logs when you catch that exception.

Comment: So it is useless out of the box... damn... Thanks anyway. I'm looking for a rolling log file listener, that deletes old files like the one in log4net, but easy to configure and set up.

Comment: I am actually trying to do that, but when attempting to delete the log file, i get exception that the file is used by another process. Before deleting im doing .flush and close on the listener any idea how to fix this ?